# How to send parameters in http post request in for data in laravel

Tags: php, android, laravel, jwt

I am trying to authorize user from android device. I integrated the JWT package in my project and made the token based authorization. Here is how my Controller looks like:

```
    class AdminLoginController extends Controller
     {
    public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware('jwt.auth',['except'=>['authenticate']]);
   }

     public function authenticate(Request $request)
      {
       $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
       try {
        // verify the credentials and create a token for the user
        if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))
         {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
        }
       } catch (JWTException $e) {
        // something went wrong
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
      }

     // if no errors are encountered we can return a JWT
      return response()->json(compact('token'));
     }
```

With this i am being to get token for the valid user request but i need to pass the parameters from the parameters section in postman.I have the put on the picture here[image: Postman Token generation] . But if i try to post parameters from the body as a form data it says invalid credentials for the same user. How can i solve it. Any kinds of help are appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fisrt step check:

```
dd($credentials);
```

The ouput should be like this:

```
array:2 [
    "email" => "kajal@gmail.com"
    "password" => "kajal1"
]
```

Second step check:

```
dd($token);
```

And show the ouput.

Comment: yeah is is coming if i do that. If i post if from params then also it is coming and if i post from form data then also it is coming. Now what should i do gentcys. :)

Comment: I did dd($token) it said undefined variables token . I did it just below $credential and above try.

Comment: You should add it after first `if` statement

Comment: like  if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials))
         { if(dd($credentials))
?

Comment: Just add it before `return response()->json(compact('token'));`

Comment: it came when i did like i mentioned earlier. like this.if (! $token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)) { if(dd($credentials)) and this came:{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOi....